# Regex in R -- extracting sub-string based on two start/stop words

Tags: regex, r, twitter

I have a character (text) column:

```
tweets <- c(
    "Drinking a Bud Light by @Budweiser @ Joe's Crab Shack http://www.joes.com",
    "Drinking a Sam Adams Winter Ale by @SamAdams @ Growler Stop http://www.growlerstop.com",
    "Drinking a Coco Loco by @NoDaBrewing @ The Corner Pub http://www.cornerpub.com"
)
```

As you can see, assume the tweets have a standard structure:

```
"Drinking a [name of beer] by @[name of brewery] @ [name of bar, notice whitespace] http://"
```

I want to use regular expressions (and `substr()`?) to create three new columns:

1. Name of the beer
2. Name of the brewery
3. Name of the bar (note that it could have white space, so needs to go to "http:")

**One step further** - how do I control for some Tweets that do not have the same structure?

Answer (score 3):

It's ugly:

```
setNames(nm=c('beer','brewery','bar'),as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,
    regmatches(tweets,regexec('^Drinking an? (.*) by @(.*) @ (.*) http://.*$',tweets))
)[,-1L]));
##                   beer     brewery              bar
## 1            Bud Light   Budweiser Joe's Crab Shack
## 2 Sam Adams Winter Ale    SamAdams     Growler Stop
## 3            Coco Loco NoDaBrewing   The Corner Pub
```

See [`regexec()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) and [`regmatches()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regmatches.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
    do.call(rbind,strsplit(gsub('.*\\ba\\b(.*) by @(.*) @(.*) http.*','\\1|\\2|\\3',tweets),'\\|'))

#       [,1]                    [,2]          [,3]               
#[1,] " Bud Light"            "Budweiser"   " Joe's Crab Shack"
#[2,] " Sam Adams Winter Ale" "SamAdams"    " Growler Stop"    
#[3,] " Coco Loco"            "NoDaBrewing" " The Corner Pub"
```